# calling attributes from other classes error

Tags: python

I am working on a project for my CS class, I am near where I fell comfortable to call it complete, but I am getting this error:

```
exceptions.AttributeError: type object 'protaganist' has no attribute 'hearts'
```

also i am trying to make my protaganist class move up.... i have tried

```
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
   self.y += self.dy          # (where dy was defined as 10 in init)
```

i dont know what else to try

lastly how i might set somthing with a random position of x with a set y position

it highlights here: ( it is calling another classe's attribute, but i dnt know why its causing error:

```
class coinandheartscore(gameEngine.SuperSprite):
                    def __init__(self, scene):
                        gameEngine.SuperSprite.__init__(self, scene)
                        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("None", 50)

                    def update(self):
                        self.text = "hearts X: %d, Coins X: %d" % (protaganist.hearts, protaganist.coins)
                        self.image = self.font.render(self.text, 1, (255, 255, 0))
                        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

here is my overall code:

```
            import gameEngine
            import pygame
            import math

            pygame.init()

            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))


            pygame.mixer.init()

            sndAtk = pygame.mixer.Sound("OOT_AdultLink_Attack1.wav")
            sndWalk = pygame.mixer.Sound("OOT_Steps_Dirt1.wav")
            sndPoof = pygame.mixer.Sound("OOT_Enemy_Poof1.wav")
            sndWalk.set_volume(.1)
            sndAtk.set_volume(.5)
            sndPoof.set_volume(.9)
            #sndRun = pygame.mixer.Sound("")
            #goal is to create a game
            #must have menu to start game
            #menu should have a start and quit button.. start runs gaming operations and quit exits program
            #sprites for character and enemies and bullets maybe, use one large image and simply move visibiliy
            #this saves memory as 1 image is loaded instead of many

            """
            protaganist is our hero sprite
            should run left and right, jump left and right
            and attack left and right...
            I might add in the bow and jump attack
            """

            class scrollinggrass(gameEngine.SuperSprite):
                def __init__(self, scene):
                    gameEngine.SuperSprite.__init__(self, scene)
                    self.setImage("gamebackground.jpg")
                    self.rect = self.imageMaster.get_rect()
                    self.setPosition((400,247))
                    self.checkKeys()
                    self.dy = 3


                def checkKeys(self):


                    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                        self.forward(-6)
                        sndWalk.play()

                    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                        self.forward(6)
                        sndWalk.play()



            class coins(gameEngine.SuperSprite):
                def __init__(self, scene):
                    gameEngine.SuperSprite.__init__(self, scene)
                    self.loadImages()
                    self.image = self.imageMaster
                    self.frame = -1

                    self.pause = 0
                    self.delay = 3

                def loadImages(self):

                    self.coinImgList = []

                    for i in range(3):
                        nameImage = "linkimages/coins/greenrupee%d.png" % i
                        self.setImage(nameImage)
                        tempImage = self.imageMaster
                        transparentColor = tempImage.get_at((1,1))
                        tempImage.set_colorkey(transparentColor)
                        self.coinImgList.append(tempImage)

                def update(self):
                    self.pause += .25
                    if self.pause >= self.delay:
                        self.pause = 0
                        self.frame += 1
                        if self.frame >= len(self.coinImgList):
                            self.frame = 0
                        self.image = self.coinImgList[self.frame]






            class hearts(gameEngine.SuperSprite):
                def __init__(self, scene):
                    gameEngine.SuperSprite.__init__(self, scene)

                    self.setImage("heart.png")
                    self.setTransparentColor = self.imageMaster.get_at((1,1))
                    self.imageMaster.set_colorkey(self.setTransparentColor)

                    self.setPosition((550 , 30))

            class badguy(gameEngine.SuperSprite):
                def __init__(self, scene):
                    gameEngine.SuperSprite.__init__(self, scene)
                    self.setImage("badguy1.png")
                    self.setTransparentColor = self.imageMaster.get_at((1,1))
                    self.imageMaster.set_colorkey(self.setTransparentColor)
                    self.rect = self.imageMaster.get_rect()
              #      self.CONTINUE = 4
                    self.boundAction = self.CONTINUE
                    self.health = 2
                    self.DEAD = 1
                    self.state = 0
                    self.setPosition((200,375))
                    self.checkKeys()
                def checkKeys(self):

                    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                        self.forward(-3)


                    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                        self.forward(3)

                def reset(self):
                    self.setPosition((1000, 375))


                    self.health = 2

              #  def update(self):


            class protaganist(gameEngine.SuperSprite):
                def __init__(self, scene):
                    gameEngine.SuperSprite.__init__(self, scene)

                    self.imageList = []

                    self.pause = 0
                    self.delay = 3

                    self.rect = self.imageMaster.get_rect()
                    self.STANDING = 0
                    self.RIGHT = 0
                    self.LEFT = 1
                    self.direction = self.RIGHT
                    self.RUNNING = 1
                    self.ATTACKING = 2
                    self.JUMPING = 3
                    self.DEAD = 10

                    self.frame = -1
                    self.state = self.STANDING

                    self.coins = 0
                    self.hearts = 1
                    self.heartPts = self.hearts * 3

                    self.stats()
                    self.dy = 20
                    self.loadImages()
                    self.image = self.imageMaster
                    self.checkKeys()

                def stats(self):
            #sets it up so each heart is essentially 3 hit points
                    if self.heartPts >= 3:
                        self.hearts = 1
                    elif self.heartPts >= 6:
                        self.hearts = 2
                    elif self.heartPts == 9:
                        self.hearts = 3
                    elif self.heartPts > 9:
                        self.heartPts = 9
            # changes state to dead if hp == 0
                    if self.heartPts == 0:
                        self.state = DEAD


                def loadImages(self):

                    self.setImage("heroSTANDINGLeft.gif")
                    self.setTransparentColor = self.imageMaster.get_at((1,1))
                    self.imageMaster.set_colorkey(self.setTransparentColor)
                    self.imageSTANDINGLeft = self.imageMaster

                    self.setImage("heroSTANDING.gif")
                    self.setTransparentColor = self.imageMaster.get_at((1,1))
                    self.imageMaster.set_colorkey(self.setTransparentColor)
                    self.imageSTANDING = self.imageMaster


                    self.heroATKList = []
                    self.heroATKleft = []
                    self.heroDEAD = []
                    self.heroRUNList = []
                    self.heroRUNLeftList = []

                    for i in range(4):
                        nameImage = "linkimages/DEAD/heroDEAD%d.gif" % i
                        self.setImage(nameImage)
                        tempImage = self.imageMaster
                        transparentColor = tempImage.get_at((1,1))
                        tempImage.set_colorkey(transparentColor)
                        self.heroDEAD.append(tempImage)

                    for i in range(5):
                        nameImage = "linkimages/runningRIGHT/heroRUN%d.gif" % i
                        self.setImage(nameImage)
                        tempImage = self.imageMaster
                        transparentColor = tempImage.get_at((1,1))
                        tempImage.set_colorkey(transparentColor)
                        self.heroRUNList.append(tempImage)

                    for i in range(5):
                        nameImage = "linkimages/runningLEFT/heroRUN%d.gif" % i
                        self.setImage(nameImage)
                        tempImage = self.imageMaster
                        transparentColor = tempImage.get_at((1,1))
                        tempImage.set_colorkey(transparentColor)
                        self.heroRUNLeftList.append(tempImage)

                    for i in range(4):
                        nameImage = "linkimages/ATTACKING/heroATTACKING%d.gif" % i
                        self.setImage(nameImage)
                        tempImage = self.imageMaster
                        transparentColor = tempImage.get_at((1,1))
                        tempImage.set_colorkey(transparentColor)
                        self.heroATKList.append(tempImage)
                    for i in range(4):
                        nameImage = "linkimages/ATTACKING/heroATTACKINGLeft%d.gif" % i
                        self.setImage(nameImage)
                        tempImage = self.imageMaster
                        transparentColor = tempImage.get_at((1,1))
                        tempImage.set_colorkey(transparentColor)
                        self.heroATKleft.append(tempImage)

                def update(self):

                    self.rect = self.imageMaster.get_rect()
                    self.rect.x = 275
                    self.rect.y = 350
                    if self.state == self.STANDING:
                        if self.direction == self.RIGHT:
                            self.image = self.imageSTANDING
                            self.setPosition((200,200))
                        elif self.direction == self.LEFT:
                            self.image = self.imageSTANDINGLeft
                    if self.state == self.RUNNING:
                        if self.direction == self.RIGHT:
                            self.frame += 1
                            if self.frame >= len(self.heroRUNList):
                                self.frame = 0
                            self.image = self.heroRUNList[self.frame]
                        elif self.direction == self.LEFT:
                            self.frame += 1
                            if self.frame >= len(self.heroRUNLeftList):
                                self.frame = 0
                            self.image = self.heroRUNLeftList[self.frame]

                    if self.state == self.DEAD:
                        self.frame += 1
                        if self.frame >= len(self.heroDEAD):
                            self.frame = 0
                        self.image = self.heroDEAD[self.frame]

                    self.pause += .5
                    if self.pause >= self.delay:
                        self.pause = 0


                        if self.state == self.ATTACKING:
                            if self.direction == self.RIGHT:
                                self.frame += 1
                                sndAtk.play()
                                if self.frame >= len(self.heroATKList):
                                    self.frame = 0
                                self.image = self.heroATKList[self.frame]

                            elif self.direction == self.LEFT:
                                self.frame += 1
                                sndAtk.play()
                                if self.frame >= len(self.heroATKleft):
                                    self.frame = 0
                                self.image = self.heroATKleft[self.frame]


                def checkKeys(self):


                    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                        self.direction = self.RIGHT
                        self.state = self.RUNNING
                        self.x += self.dx
                    else:
                        self.state = self.STANDING
                    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                        self.state = self.RUNNING
                        self.direction = self.LEFT

                    if keys[pygame.K_g]:
                        self.state = self.ATTACKING
                        #sndAtk.play()

                    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                        self.addDY(3)

                    if self.state == self.DEAD:
                        self.image = self.deadImgList[0]
                        self.frame += 1
                        self.image = self.deadImgList[self.frame]
                        #self.image = self.image.get_rect()
                        #self.rect.center = (320, 240)



            class coinandheartscore(gameEngine.SuperSprite):
                def __init__(self, scene):
                    gameEngine.SuperSprite.__init__(self, scene)
                    self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("None", 50)

                def update(self):
                    self.text = "hearts X: %d, Coins X: %d" % (protaganist.hearts, protaganist.coins)
                    self.image = self.font.render(self.text, 1, (255, 255, 0))
                    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


            class game(gameEngine.Scene):
                def __init__ (self):
                    gameEngine.Scene.__init__(self)



                    pygame.display.set_caption("Link's Mediocre Adventure")

                    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
                    background.fill((0, 0, 0))
                    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))



                    coin = coins(self)
                    pro = protaganist(self)
                    baddy = badguy(self)
                    baddy1 = badguy(self)
                    heart = hearts(self)
                    grass = scrollinggrass(self)
                    score = coinandheartscore(self)



                    goodlySprites = self.makeSpriteGroup((grass, coin, pro, heart))
                    baddySprites = self.makeSpriteGroup((baddy, baddy1))
                    cnhrtSprites = self.makeSpriteGroup((score))

                    self.addGroup((cnhrtSprites))
                    self.addGroup((goodlySprites))
                    self.addGroup((baddySprites))

                    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
                    keepGoing = True
                    while keepGoing:
                        clock.tick(30)
                        for event in pygame.event.get():
                            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                                keepGoing = False



                        if pro.state == pro.ATTACKING:
                            if pro.collidesGroup(baddySprites):
                                baddy.health -= 1
                                baddy1.health -= 1
                                if baddy.health == 0:
                                    sndPoof.play()
                                    baddy.reset()
                                elif baddy1.health == 0:
                                    sndPoof.play()
                                    baddy1.reset()
                        elif pro.state != pro.ATTACKING:
                            if pro.collidesGroup(baddySprites):
                                pro.heartPts -= 1

                        baddy.checkKeys()
                        grass.checkKeys()
                        pro.checkKeys()
                        pro.loadImages()

                        goodlySprites.clear(screen, background)
                        baddySprites.clear(screen, background)
                        cnhrtSprites.clear(screen, background)
                        goodlySprites.update()
                        baddySprites.update()
                        cnhrtSprites.update()

                        goodlySprites.draw(screen)
                        baddySprites.draw(screen)
                        cnhrtSprites.draw(screen)

                        pygame.display.flip()



            def main():

                game.start()

            if __name__ == "__main__":
                game()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, if you have two questions (even about the same piece of code), you should post two separate questions on Stack Overflow.  That said...

**1:  Moving Up**

The code you quoted in your question looks OK.  Unfortunately, it's nothing like the code you're actually running in `protaganist.checkKeys`:

```
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    self.addDY(3)
```

There *is* no `protaganist.addDY` method, so trying to call it should raise an exception.  The hard-wired argument to the non-existent method is 3, not 10.  Finally (to correct your comment), `protaganist.__init__` sets `protaganist.dy` to 20, not 10.

**2:  AttributeError**

Your `protaganist` class has no `hearts` attribute, which is almost exactly what the error message said.  (Note that it's typically spelled with an "o": protag**o**nist.)

*Instances* of your `protaganist` class *do* have a `hearts` attribute, but you can't access that by going through the class name.  (How would the Python interpreter know which of possibly-many `protaganist` instances you meant?)

To get a particular `protaganist` object's `hearts` value, you'll need a reference to that *specific* instance:

```
class coinandheartscore(gameEngine.SuperSprite):

    # New protagonist parameter is required.
    def __init__(self, scene, protagonist):
        gameEngine.SuperSprite.__init__(self, scene)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("None", 50)
        # Save it for later use.
        self.protagonist = protagonist

    def update(self):
        # self.protagonist refers to _one_ specific
        # protaganist instance, which _does_ have
        # hearts and coins attributes.
        self.text = "hearts X: %d, Coins X: %d" % (
          self.protagonist.hearts,
          self.protagonist.coins,
          )
        # Remainder unchanged...
```

Later, in the `game.__init__` method, you'll have to provide the new argument when you instantiate `coinandheartscore`:

```
# New self.pro argument.
score = coinandheartscore(self, self.pro)
```

**3:  PEP-8**

Finally, I second xnx's comments about naming conventions...  The strange names made this *much* harder to read than it had to be.

Although xnx didn't link to [PEP-8](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in his answer, it is *literally* the first Google result.  He or she was specifically talking about the section on [Naming Conventions](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

**4:  Freebies**

`protaganist.checkKeys`: `d` and `a` are not the inverses you would expect.  `d` adds `self.dx` ( which does not exist) to `self.x`, while `a` adds nothing.

`protaganist.stats` sets `self.state` to `DEAD`, which does not exist.  You probably meant `self.DEAD`.

In general, **test more and code less**.  The more you write between tests, the more bugs you will have to track down, and the more places they can be hiding.

Comment: awesome thank you it worked! 2 things: 1st, I'm not sure what you and the guy above are talking about when it comes to names... though i do usually camelcase ie: coinAndHeartScore.     2nd any ideas on my moving up problem?

Comment: @Cyrus:  I've updated the answer.  This should really be separate questions, though.  (I'd missed the question about the "move up" key because it was buried in a completely different question.)

Answer (score 1):

At least one of the problems is in your naming of your classes: the PEP8 convention calls for capitalized class names (`Protagonist`) and lower-case instances of them (`pro`). You've called your class `protagonist` and instantiated as `pro`. It looks like you're referring to `protagonist.hearts` (no such class attribute exists) when you mean `pro.hearts` (attribute of an instance of the `protagonist` class.

Comment: I tried changing it to pro.hearts and it says pro is not defined, it assumes its a variable?

Comment: See Kevin J. Chase's answer -- the `coinandheartscore` doesn't know anything about `pro`: pass it to the `update()` method as he suggests.